# Automatic generation of pure function

Tags: pure-function

My main problem consist in the creation of a sort function which wolud be used inside `SortBy`.

***Introduction***

---

The principle of the sort to apply is the following (for a list of points in 2 dimension) :

```
listosort = {{4, 9}, {-4, -9}, {-5, -7}, {-4, 4}, {-2, -1}, {-6, -9}, {-5, 0}};  
SortBy[listosort, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &];
```

We can noticed that :
- The sorting function allows you to sort columns by columns.
- The sorting function is a pure function.
- We can have an ascending or a descending sort with the use of 1 or -1.

***Problem***

---

I have to deal with the lists whose dimensions can vary. And I don't want to rewrite the pure function inside `SortBy`.

So I wrote the following code :

```
SPart[x_][y_] := Part[y, x];
ListSPart[x_] := (SPart[#] & /@ (Range@Length@x))*((x) /. {"max" -> 1, "min" -> 0});
SortVDL[x_, y_] := SortBy[x, ListSPart[y]]
```

So I can write now :

```
SortVDL[listosort, {1, -1}]
SortVDL[listosort, {"max", "min"}] (*equivalent*)
```

Instead of writing :

```
SortBy[listosort, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &];
```

***Objectives***

---

It's important to :
- Be able to handle list with elements of n dimensions.
- Be able to choose an ascending or descendand sorting for each column. 
- I don't need to treat list of non-numerical value.

Examples of possible writing :

```
SortVDL[listosort, {1, -1}]         (* 2D *)
SortVDL[listosort, {1, 1}]          (* 2D *)
SortVDL[listosort, {1, -1, 1, 1}]   (* 4D *)
```

***Question***

---

My code unfortunately does not work.

Indeed, the following lines of code :

```
SortVDL[listosort, {1, 1}];
SortBy[listosort, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];

SortVDL[listosort, {-1, 1}];
SortBy[listosort, {-#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];

SortVDL[listosort, {-1, -1}];
SortBy[listosort, {-#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &];
```

are not equivalent. 
SortVDL seems to always give the same result. Why ?
Is there a method to automatically generate reliable pure functions ?

***Resume***

---

Code n°1

```
F11[x_][y_] := Part[y, x];
F1[x_] := (F11[#] & /@ (Range@Length@x))*x;
F1[{1, -1, 1}];
```

Code n°2

```
F2[x_] := Function[Evaluate[Thread[F1[x] Slot /@ (ConstantArray[1, Length@x])]]];
F2[{1, -1, 1}];
```

Code n°3 (Xavier's answer)

```
F3[x_] := Activate[(Evaluate[x*Table[Inactive[Part][#, i], {i, Length@x}]]) &];
F3[{1, -1, 1}];
```

Code n°1 >> Don't work with `SortBy` >> See Xavier's answer.
Code n°2 >> Don't work with `SortBy` >> See Xavier's answer.
Code n°3 >> Work with `SortBy` >> See Xavier's answer.

***Final Answer***

---

Xavier's answer :

```
mySort[list_, coef_] := 
  SortBy[list, 
   Activate[(Evaluate[
       coef Table[
         Inactive[Part][#, i], {i, Dimensions[list][[2]]}]]) &]];
```

Ciao's answer :

```
numColSorter[list_, sortord_] := 
  list[[Ordering[Transpose[Transpose[list]*sortord]]]];
```

Benchmarks :

```
data1 = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {10^6, 2}];
```

`mySort` >> 0.733489 s
`numColSorter` >> 0.282189 s

Comment: Don't have time right now to address the "...creation of a sort function..." aspect of this, but if the question changes to admit solving the end goal (arbitrary sorting by columns) by other means, there are efficient ways to do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This update addresses the why-questions about the codes 1, 2 and 3 in OP's **Resume** update. I will use the following list (reduced version of `listosort`) throughout the explanations:*

```
list = {{4, 9}, {-4, -9}, {-5, -7}, {-4, 4}, {-6, -9}, {-5, 0}};
```

---

**Code 1**

```
F11[x_][y_] := Part[y, x];
F1[x_] := (F11[#] & /@ (Range@Length@x))*x;
```

Let's consider the list `{1, -1}` as argument. We have

```
SortBy[list, F1[{1, -1}]]
(* {{-6, -9}, {-5, -7}, {-5, 0}, {-4, -9}, {-4, 4}, {4, 9}} *)

SortBy[list, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &]
(* {{-6, -9}, {-5, 0}, {-5, -7}, {-4, 4}, {-4, -9}, {4, 9}} *)
```

To understand why this is happening, we can take a closer look at `F1` and how `SortBy` effectively works.

**a)** The function `F1` evaluates for `{1, -1}` to

```
F1[{1, -1}]
(* {F11[1], -F11[2]} *)
```

The second argument of `SortBy` can be a function (usage lines of the reference page), or a list of functions (section Details of the reference page). Here, `F1[{1, -1}]` evaluates to a list of function.

**b)** In the section Properties and Relations of `SortBy`, an effective equivalence is given:

> SortBy[*e*, *f*] is equivalent to Sort[{*f*[#], #} & /@ *e*][[All, -1]]

For a list of functions, this translates to

> SortBy[*e*, {*f1*, *f2*, ...}] is equivalent to Sort[{{*f1*[#], *f2*[#], ...}, #} & /@ *e*][[All, -1]]

Taking an arbitrary example for this last quote:

```
SortBy[list, {Abs, #[[2]] &}] === 
     Sort[{{Abs[#], #[[2]] &[#]}, #} & /@ list][[All, -1]]
(* True *)
```

Going back to `F1`, we can try this equivalence by writing (I'm using directly the output of `F1[{1, -1}]` given above)

```
SortBy[list, {F11[1], -F11[2]}] === 
    Sort[{{F11[1][#], -F11[2][#]}, #} & /@ list][[All, -1]]
(* False *)
```

This equivalence is not correct because the element `-F11[2][#]` is actually not of the form `f2[#]` (see the second quote above), with `f2` corresponding to `-F11[2]`. In `-F11[2][#]`, the part `F11[2]` is bound to `[#]` first, and then to `-`. The correct writing is instead

```
SortBy[list, {F11[1], -F11[2]}] === 
    Sort[{{F11[1][#], (-F11[2])[#]}, #} & /@ list][[All, -1]]
(* True *)
```

In this situation, which is the one of interest to understand why `code 1` does not yield the expected result, the evaluation of `(-F11[2])[#]` for any element of `list` will not use the definition of `F11`. For instance consider:

```
(-F11[2])[First[list]]
(* (-F11[2])[{4, 9}] *)
```

`SortBy` will used expressions of this form to sort the elements of `list` when there is a tie on the first element of each sublist. The thing is that such a sorting will always be in the canonical order. We can see that from the equivalence with the one-argument form of `Sort` in the (second) quote above, and also in action with

```
SortBy[list, {F11[1], -F11[2]}] === SortBy[list, {F11[1]}]
(* True *)
```

---

**Code 2**

```
F2[x_] := Function[Evaluate[Thread[F1[x] Slot /@ (ConstantArray[1, Length@x])]]];
```

We consider again the list `{1, -1}` as argument. We have

```
SortBy[list, F2[{1, -1}]]
(* {{-6, -9}, {-5, 0}, {-5, -7}, {-4, -9}, {-4, 4}, {4, 9}} *)

SortBy[list, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &]
(* {{-6, -9}, {-5, 0}, {-5, -7}, {-4, 4}, {-4, -9}, {4, 9}} *)
```

Here the difference is due to the function constructed by `F2`. We have

```
F2[{1, -1}]
(* {F11[1] #1, -F11[2] #1} & *)
```

Using this time the first quote of the equivalence above:

```
SortBy[list, {F11[1] #, -F11[2] #} &] === 
    Sort[{{F11[1] #, -F11[2] #} &[#], #} & /@ list][[All, -1]]
(* True *)
```

The definition of `F11` won't be used since we do not have an expression of the form `F11[x][y]`. What it is doing instead is evaluating elements of `list` as (for, e.g., `{-4, -9}` and `{-4, 4}`),

```
{F11[1] #, -F11[2] #} &[{-4, -9}]
(* {{-4 F11[1], -9 F11[1]}, {4 F11[2], 9 F11[2]}} *)

{F11[1] #, -F11[2] #} &[{-4, 4}]
(* {{-4 F11[1], 4 F11[1]}, {4 F11[2], -4 F11[2]}} *)
```

and sorting `list` in the canonical order with respect to these values. Indeed we have:

```
Order[%%, %]
(* 1 *)
```

This explains the difference we noted above.

---

**Code 3** *(see below the original post)*

```
mySort[list_, coef_] := 
   SortBy[list, 
      Activate[(
         Evaluate[coef Table[Inactive[Part][#, i], {i, Dimensions[list][[2]]}]]
      ) &]
];
```

Taking again the argument `{1, -1}` for comparison, this time we get

```
SortBy[list, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &] === mySort[list, {1, -1}]
(* True *)
```

Here, the idea was to construct a function given to `SortBy` that won't be evaluated again and again for each element of `list` *during* the sorting process. Compare for instance with

```
mySort2[list_, coef_] := 
  SortBy[list, (coef Table[Part[#, i], {i, Dimensions[list][[2]]}]) &]

mySort[list, {1, -1}] === mySort2[list, {1, -1}]
(* True *)

SeedRandom[1];
ll = RandomInteger[10, {10^6, 2}];

mySort[ll, {1, -1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.74406, Null} *)

mySort2[ll, {1, -1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.845808, Null} *)
```

This is a small gain, but still. Anyhow, this is the reason for `Evaluate` in `mySort`. Since `Part` needs to be prevented from evaluating (otherwise it will return an error), I used `Inactive` and then `Activate` after the construction of the function.

---

**Original post**

```
mySort[list_, coef_] := 
   SortBy[list, 
          Activate[(
             Evaluate[coef Table[Inactive[Part][#, i], {i, Dimensions[list][[2]]}]]
          ) &]
   ];
```

Taking your examples,

```
listosort = {{4, 9}, {-4, -9}, {-5, -7}, {-4, 4}, {-2, -1}, {-6, -9}, {-5, 0}};

mySort[listosort, {1, 1}]
% === SortBy[listosort, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]

(* {{-6, -9}, {-5, -7}, {-5, 0}, {-4, -9}, {-4, 4}, {-2, -1}, {4, 9}} *)
(* True *)

mySort[listosort, {-1, 1}]
% === SortBy[listosort, {-#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]

(* {{4, 9}, {-2, -1}, {-4, -9}, {-4, 4}, {-5, -7}, {-5, 0}, {-6, -9}} *)
(* True *)

mySort[listosort, {-1, -1}]
% === SortBy[listosort, {-#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &]

(* {{4, 9}, {-2, -1}, {-4, 4}, {-4, -9}, {-5, 0}, {-5, -7}, {-6, -9}} *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: N.B.: This will fail for non-numeric values in the list to be sorted. Don't know if that matters to OP however. E.g., given `{{1, aa}, {vv, vv}, {1, 5}, {aa, 5}, {5, vv}}`, sorting as `{1,-1}`, yours gives `{{1, 5}, {1, aa}, {5, vv}, {aa, 5}, {vv, vv}}` and it should be `{{1, aa}, {1, 5}, {5, vv}, {aa, 5}, {vv, vv}}`.

Comment: @ciao Ah, good point. I think it depends on what OP means by `{1, -1}`. I interpret it as the coefficients to be allocated to `{#[[1]], #[[2]]}`, so the sorting `{{1, 5}, {1, aa}, ...}` would be correct. `SortBy[{e1, e2, ...}, f]` sorts its elements `ei` such that the `f[ei]` are in canonical order, and `Order[{1, -5}, {1, -aa}]` returns `1`. If by `-1` OP means "not in canonical order", I agree with you, my code is not correct. Perhaps OP could clarify this point.

Comment: Ciao _ I don't need to treat list with non-numeric values.
Xavier _ Your interpretation is good.

Comment: @Xavier. Thank for your answer.

Comment: @Doedalos: In that case, `numColSorter[list_, sortord_] := 
  list[[Ordering[Transpose[Transpose[list]*sortord]]]];` is cleaner and faster...

Comment: @Doedalos You're welcome. I've made an update following yours.

Comment: @Xavier. Thank you so much for your detailed and comprehensive reply.

Comment: @ciao. Thank you for your effective code.

Answer (score 0):

First, DO NOT use uppercase to start a variable.

Second, does this work

```
sort[x_List] := SortBy[x, {#[[1]], #[[Dimensions[x][[2]]]]} &]
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution ! Unfortunately, if your code can treat list with points of n dimensions, we can't choice an ascending/descending sort for each column.